# Efficient way to manipulate the structure of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"node":"A","month":1,"val":-77},
    {"node":"A","month":2,"val":0},
    {"node":"B","month":1,"val":-16},
    {"node":"B","month":2,"val":0}
])
```

I'd like to modify this so that each month is within the same row and the month value is the key to the value of 'val':

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"node":"A", 1: -77, 2: 0},
    {"node":"B", 1: -16, 2: 0}
])
```

Comment: `df.pivot('node', 'month', 'val')`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pandas.pivot_table()`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"node":"A","month":1,"val":-77},
    {"node":"A","month":2,"val":0},
    {"node":"B","month":1,"val":-16},
    {"node":"B","month":2,"val":0}
])

df=df.pivot_table(index="node", columns="month", values="val").reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
month node   1  2
0        A -77  0
1        B -16  0
```